# How to set a certain number of spaces or indents before a Paragraph in Google Docs using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, paragraph

I have a 20 line script, and I want to make sure that each paragraph is indented exactly once.

```
function myFunction() {
  /*
  This function turns the document's format into standard MLA.
  */
  
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.setFontSize(12); // Set the font size of the contents of the documents to 9
  body.setForegroundColor('#000000');
  body.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
  
  // Loops through paragraphs in body and sets each to double spaced
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  for (var i = 3; i < paragraphs.length; i++) { // Starts at 3 to exclude first 4 developer-made paragraphs
      var paragraph = paragraphs[i];
      paragraph.setLineSpacing(2);
      // Left align the first cell.
      paragraph.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
      // One indent
      paragraph.editAsText().insertText(0, "\t"); // Adds one tab every time
  }
  var bodyText = body.editAsText();
  bodyText.insertText(0, 'February 3, 1976\nMrs. Smith\nYour Name Here\nSocial Studies\n');
  bodyText.setBold(false);
}
```

The code I have tried doesn't work. But my expected results are that for every paragraph in the for loop in `myFunction()`, there are exactly 4 spaces before the first word in each paragraph.

---

Here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sMztzhOehzheRdqumC6PLnvk4qJgUCSE0irjTZ0FjTQ/edit?usp=sharing

If the user uses Autoformat, but already has the paragraphs indented...
[image: Placeholder text with indented paragraph using snipping tool]
[image: Placeholder text indented twice]

### Update

I have investigated use of the `Paragraph.setIndentFirstLine()` method. When I set it to four, it sets it to 1 space. Now I realize this is because points and spaces are not the same thing. What number do I need to multiply by to get four spaces in points?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't understand about ``But not just the top paragraph (actual paragraph not Mrs. Smith...) every paragraph, hence the for loop looping through the paragraphs.``. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191696/discussion-between-marvin-and-tanaike).

Comment: Why not to use standard methods **getIndentStart()** and **getIndentFirstLine()** of the class [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph)?

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин now that I have tested it again, this worked perfectly. When I tried this the first time it wasn't working but now for some reason it is.

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин on second thought, this does NOT work perfectly :(

Comment: I have tested both of these out in the Logger and getIndentStart always returns 0 for each paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a few basic identing operations: manual and by script.
The following image shows how to indent current paragraph (cursor stays inside this one).

[image: Manual indenting of the current paragraph]

Please note, the units are centimetres. Also note, that the paragraph does not include leading spaces or tabs, we have no need of them.

Suppose we would like to get the indent values in the script and apply them to the next paragraph. Look at the code below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ps = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  // We work with the 5-th and 6-th paragraphs indeed
  var iFirst = ps[5].getIndentFirstLine();
  var iStart = ps[5].getIndentStart();
  var iEnd = ps[5].getIndentEnd();
  Logger.log([iFirst, iStart, iEnd]);
  ps[6].setIndentFirstLine(iFirst);
  ps[6].setIndentStart(iStart);
  ps[6].setIndentEnd(iEnd);
}
```

If you run and look at the log, you will see something like this: `[92.69291338582678, 64.34645669291339, 14.173228346456694]`. No surprise, we have typographic **points** instead of **centimetres**. (1cm=28.3465pt) So we can measure and modify any paragraph indent values precisely.

**Addition**

For some reasons you might want to control spaces number at the beginning of the paragraph. It is also possible by scripting, but it has no effect on the paragraph's "left" or "right" indents.

Sample code below is for similar task: count leading spaces number of the 5-th paragraph and make the same number of spaces at the beginning of the next one.

```
function mySpaces() {
  var ps = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  // We work with the 5-th and 6-th paragraphs indeed
  var spacesCount = getLeadingSpacesCount(ps[5]);
  Logger.log(spacesCount);
  var diff = getLeadingSpacesCount(ps[6]) - spacesCount;
  if (diff > 0) {
    ps[6].editAsText().deleteText(0, diff - 1);
  } else if (diff < 0) {
    var s = Array(1 - diff).join(' ');
    ps[6].editAsText().insertText(0, s);
  }
}


function getLeadingSpacesCount(p) {
  var found = p.findText("^ +");
  return found ? found.getEndOffsetInclusive() + 1 : 0;
}
```

We have used methods **deleteText()** and **insertText()** of the class [Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) for proper corrections and **findText()** to locate the spaces if any. Note, the last method argument is a string, representing a regular expression. It matches "all leading spaces", if they exist. See [more details](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) about regular expression syntax.

Comment: Menu steps: "Format -- Align & Indent -- Indentation Options..."